# Android Studio causes Bluescreen every time

Tags: android-studio, crash, aapt

I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro and migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio.
But if i start Android Studio, "indexing" is going on and then thousand terminal windows pop up(from the aapt.exe). 
Then the bluescreen appears.(SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION, event viewer mentions "Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power")
I set JAVA_HOME to my jdk path and reinstalled Android Studio. 
It didn't help.
Do anybody has some suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem, bluescreen with different messages while building or gradle sync. Disabling "AVG" my preferred anti virus software caused the problem to vanish.

Comment: If you are not sure the following will fix in other then you could add as comment and once it's fixed then you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. I've already forgotten this problem. As said by user4965409, it was my antivirus software. I'm using avast and as I turned it off, it worked. 
So disable your antivirus, if you have similiar problems with Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

If disabling anti-virus doesn't help, it can be a faulty RAM module. This was the problem in my case.

You can check for faults by creating a Bootable USB of this utility.
https://www.memtest86.com/index.html